# Keyboard Capture on a Web Page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to implement a JavaScript component that captures key-inputs and creates a command prompt interface for the web, I don't want to use text-fields

It's easy to capture input from keys as follows:

```
$('*').bind( 'keypress', keypressCaptureFunction )
```

but the bubbling of events is giving me multiple events per key-press, also, using '*' is a bit of a cheat because I don't know what to call `bind()` on...

How do I properly catch a keypress event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(document).bind('keypress', keypressCaptureFunction);

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).bind( 'keypress', keypressCaptureFunction );
```

This will listen for the bubble up at the document level and bind one event handler instead of many.

Answer (score 1):

There are also the `.keypress()`, `.keydown()`, and `.keyup()` shortcuts. Such as:

```
$(document).keydown(keypressCaptureFunction);
```